# Row number in wpf datagrid row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have datagrid bound a ICollectionView list object. Basically the rows are filtered based on a value in one column. Now there is a index column in each of the row. This is basically the row number . Since the rows are filtered the row number changes. How to handle this ?

Basically DataGrid is bound to a list of class object.

```
 Class city
 {
   Int Index;
   String Name;
   string location; 
  }

 List<city> Cities;
```

When i create the object, index has the value according to the no of items in the index. So the first object will have index =0, second will have index=1 and so on.  Index is a column in the grid. Now lets say i have 2 objects with location Dubai. and one with Cairo(3rd object , with Index=3). When i select Cairo Only that row will be displayed. But since i have added the index earlier , index number=3 where as i want it to be 1 since there is only one row after the filter.

Comment: Please post some code to facilitate us in helping you. 
It sounds like you are rebuilding your index  _AFTER_ applying the filter, which is causing the problem?

Comment: added few more description please check.

Comment: What do you indend to do with this `Index`  property. Is it part of Business Logic or you have created this for display purpose in the View? If it is only for Display have a look at implementing `AlternationIndex`

Comment: @Bharathram Attiyannan its only or display purpose.. could you give me sample code .. i did not get what you mean by AlternateIndex

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [AlternationIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you want to show Row Index. Two things are important when you are using `AlternationIndex`:

- Set `AlternationCount` for the control. This is like a counting limit for `AlternationIndex` after that it will restart from 0 if your number of elements exceeds that count. Ideally you can bind it to Count Of Items if you dont want it to restart from 0
- When Binding AlternationIndex be mindful of the Source. For ListBox it will be `{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}` for others it can be `{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}`

Try this Sample below:

```
<ListBox Name="CityListBox" AlterationCount={Binding CountOfItems}
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="City">
            <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Name}"></Run>
                    <Run Text=" : "></Run>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Country}"></Run>
                    <Run Text=" : "></Run>
                    <Run Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                                Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Output**

```
CityA : CountryA : 0
CityB : CountryB : 1
CityC : CountryC : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

what will typically need to do is to set the value for index first, then apply the filter.

include the System.Linq namespace and add the following

```
cities = cities.Select((item, index) =>
        new city()
        {
            Index = index,
            Name = item.Name,
            location =  item.location
        });
```

This will bring back a list of cities where the first index would be zero. If you want it to start from one simply change it  to :

```
cities = cities.Select((item, index) =>
        new city()
        {
            Index = index + 1,
            Name = item.Name,
            location =  item.location
        });
```

After this has been completed you should apply your filter, which shouldn't be overridden unless you are changing the values.